# If $P$ is the midpoint of side $BC$ of triangle $ABC$, and if $AB<AC$, prove that $\angle PAC<\angle BAP$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

This is a question from College Geometry by Howard Eves -  Section 1.1 - Problem 10

> If $P$ is the midpoint of side $BC$ of triangle $ABC$, and if $AB<AC$, prove that $\angle PAC<\angle BAP$

I am not sure how to start this proof, I know midpoint is defined as:

$$P=\frac{1}{2}\left(B+C\right)$$

I did a graph, but I am not sure how to proceed.

[image: P should be M]

Comment: Immediate from [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).

Comment: Why you have P. Should not it be M?

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;S_{ABP}=S_{APC}\,$, so $\;\frac{1}{2}\, AB\cdot AP\cdot \sin(\angle BAP) = \frac{1}{2}\, AP\cdot AC\cdot \sin(\angle PAC)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate triangle $ABP$ to $A'PC$, to obtain parallelogram $AA'CP$ (figure below): in triangle $A'OC$ you have $OC>OA'$, [whence](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI18.html) $\angle OA'C>\angle OCA'$.

[image]